# How to 'activate' SLF4J logging in JBoss6 AS

Tags: java, logging, jboss, slf4j

***Given:***

JBoss 6 Application Server M3

```
$ ls -la $JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/slf4j-*
-rwx------+ common/lib/slf4j-api.jar
-rwx------+ common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar
```

I believe that the above libs provide the bridge between SLF4J and the JBoss Logging system.

My Web application relies on SLF4J for logging.  Though, I don't package any slf4j libs with my WAR.

```
$ jar tvf proj-web/target/proj.war | grep slf4
$
```

(If I include them, doesn't make any difference)

My jboss-logging.xml has set the level for the CONSOLE handler to DEBUG

```
$ more server/default/deploy/jboss-logging.xml
...
   <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true" target="System.out">
      <error-manager>
         <only-once/>
      </error-manager>
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
```

***Question:***

What did I forget to get my logging output into the JBoss logging system?  I don't even see a TRACE that he *tries* to **bind** the **JBoss Logging system** to **SLF4J**.

**=====[ UPDATE ]=====**

It *does* actually work!!  (without further configuration)

I just changed my code from `logger.debug("abc")` to `logger.info("xyz")` and now i do have logging output.

=> So it looks like I'm simply not able to get get log-level filtering right...    [to be continued]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my updated question.

As it is so different from the original question, I've opened a new item:

[SLF4J logger.debug() does not get logged in JBoss 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419394/slf4j-logger-debug-does-not-get-logged-in-jboss-6)