# SLF4J logger.debug() does not get logged in JBoss 6

Tags: java, logging, jboss, slf4j

**Context:** JBoss Application Server 6

I am relying on `slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar` to bind slf4j to the JBoss log manager.

All `logger.info()` output is **correctly logged**.

However, `logger.debug()` output **never appears** in the log stream.

Even though jboss-logging.xml has set the level to `DEBUG` for the CONSOLE logger...

```
   <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true" target="System.out">
      ...
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
      ...
   </console-handler>
```

Does anybody see why my debug details never reach the log stream?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As from JBoss 6, the log manager and jboss-logging.xml are proprietary.

The key is in the root-logger definition at the end of the config file:

The default defintion caps **all output to whatever hander** at `INFO` level:

```
   <root-logger>
      <level name="${jboss.server.log.threshold:INFO}"/>
      <handlers>
         <handler-ref name="CONSOLE"/>
         <handler-ref name="ERROR"/>
         <handler-ref name="FILE"/>
      </handlers>
   </root-logger>
```

Changing this to

```
   <root-logger>
      <level name="${jboss.server.log.threshold:DEBUG}"/>
      <handlers>
```

opens the gate for all possible DEBUG information.

Probably too much DEBUG information.  Therefore, I had to add some additional filters:

```
   <logger category="org.jboss">
      <level name="INFO"/>
   </logger>

   <logger category="org.hibernate">
      <level name="INFO"/>
   </logger>

   <logger category="javax">
      <level name="INFO"/>
   </logger>

   <logger category="idealconnector">
      <level name="INFO"/>
   </logger>

   <logger category="httpclient">
      <level name="INFO"/>
   </logger>

   <logger category="my.package">
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>
```

Comment: Good to know: Any change to jboss-logging.xml is 'hot deployed' immediately.  So it is possible to change the log level of any package/class at any time - in a *running* server (!)

Comment: A side-note to this if you are running JBOSS with JBOSS-Tools from Eclipse. I did all the stuff mentioned above, but I still did not see the debug statements. The culprit was the launch configuration within eclipse. This referenced the [JBOSS-INSTALL]/bin/logging.properties file which kept the loglevel at INFO.