# Enable Hibernate logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j, jboss6.x

I'm trying to create a log of hibernate statements.
I perform my sql statements using JPA where Hibernate 2.0 is the persistence provider (my application server is JBoss AS 6.0).
I call my CRUD methods using the EntityManager interface provided by EJB 3.0.
I read many posts about enabling hinernate logging but actually i can't see any log :-(
I create a log4j.properties file and I put it in the root folder of my Netbeans project.
I put also log4j library in the classpath of the project.
My log4j.properties s the following:

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L – %m%n


log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info

 ### log just the SQL
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

### log JDBC bind parameters ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=info

### log schema export/update ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=info

### log HQL parse trees
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug

### log cache activity ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info

### log transaction activity
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=debug

### log JDBC resource acquisition
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
```

Why can't I see the log informations?
I would like see values in sql where clauses or in insert statements (actually I see only some '?')
Thanks in advance.

For clarity I put below the folder structure of my project:

```
MyProject
¦   build.xml
¦   log4j.properties
¦
+---build
¦   ¦   capitolo2-ejb.jar
¦   ¦   capitolo2-war.war
¦   ¦   JBoss4.dpf
¦   ¦
¦   +---lib
¦   ¦       log4j-1.2.15.jar
¦   ¦       slf4j-api.jar
¦   ¦       slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar
¦   ¦
¦   +---META-INF
¦           chapter2-hornetq-jms.xml
¦           jboss-app.xml
¦           log4j.properties
¦           MANIFEST.MF
¦
+---capitolo2-ejb
¦   ¦   build.xml
¦   ¦   
¦   ¦
¦   +---build
¦   ¦   +---classes
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   .netbeans_automatic_build
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   .netbeans_update_resources
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   ¦   +---ejb
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---com
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦       +---ejb3inaction
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦           +---actionbazaar
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               +---buslogic
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               ¦       BillingException.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               ¦       OrderBillingMDB.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               ¦       PlaceBid.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               ¦       PlaceBidBean.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               ¦       PlaceOrder.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               ¦       PlaceOrderBean.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               ¦
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦               +---persistence
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦                       Bid.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦                       BillingInfo.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦                       Order.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦                       OrderStatus.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦                       ShippingInfo.class
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   ¦   +---META-INF
¦   ¦   ¦           beans.xml
¦   ¦   ¦           jboss.xml
¦   ¦   ¦           MANIFEST.MF
¦   ¦   ¦           persistence.xml
¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   +---empty
¦   ¦   +---generated-sources
¦   ¦       +---ap-source-output
¦   +---dist
¦   ¦       capitolo2-ejb.jar
¦   ¦
¦   +---lib
¦   ¦       log4j-1.2.15.jar
¦   ¦
¦   +---nbproject
¦   ¦   ¦   ant-deploy.xml
¦   ¦   ¦   build-impl.xml
¦   ¦   ¦   genfiles.properties
¦   ¦   ¦   project.properties
¦   ¦   ¦   project.xml
¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   +---private
¦   ¦           private.properties
¦   ¦           private.xml
¦   ¦
¦   +---setup
¦   ¦       jboss-ds.xml
¦   ¦
¦   +---src
¦       +---conf
¦       ¦       beans.xml
¦       ¦       jboss.xml
¦       ¦       MANIFEST.MF
¦       ¦       persistence.xml
¦       ¦
¦       +---java
¦           +---ejb
¦               +---com
¦                   +---ejb3inaction
¦                       +---actionbazaar
¦                           +---buslogic
¦                           ¦       BillingException.java
¦                           ¦       OrderBillingMDB.java
¦                           ¦       PlaceBid.java
¦                           ¦       PlaceBidBean.java
¦                           ¦       PlaceOrder.java
¦                           ¦       PlaceOrderBean.java
¦                           ¦
¦                           +---persistence
¦                                   Bid.java
¦                                   BillingInfo.java
¦                                   Order.java
¦                                   OrderStatus.java
¦                                   ShippingInfo.java
¦
+---capitolo2-war
¦   ¦   build.xml
¦   ¦
¦   +---build
¦   ¦   +---empty
¦   ¦   +---generated-sources
¦   ¦   ¦   +---ap-source-output
¦   ¦   +---lib
¦   ¦   ¦       log4j-1.2.15.jar
¦   ¦   ¦       slf4j-api.jar
¦   ¦   ¦       slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar
¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   +---web
¦   ¦       ¦   index.jsp
¦   ¦       ¦
¦   ¦       +---META-INF
¦   ¦       ¦       MANIFEST.MF
¦   ¦       ¦
¦   ¦       +---WEB-INF
¦   ¦           ¦   beans.xml
¦   ¦           ¦   jboss-web.xml
¦   ¦           ¦
¦   ¦           +---classes
¦   ¦               ¦   .netbeans_automatic_build
¦   ¦               ¦   .netbeans_update_resources
¦   ¦               ¦
¦   ¦               +---it
¦   ¦                   +---myservlets
¦   ¦                           PlaceBidServlet.class
¦   ¦                           PlaceOrderServlet.class
¦   ¦
¦   +---dist
¦   ¦       capitolo2-war.war
¦   ¦
¦   +---nbproject
¦   ¦   ¦   ant-deploy.xml
¦   ¦   ¦   build-impl.xml
¦   ¦   ¦   genfiles.properties
¦   ¦   ¦   project.properties
¦   ¦   ¦   project.xml
¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   +---private
¦   ¦           private.properties
¦   ¦           private.xml
¦   ¦
¦   +---setup
¦   ¦       jboss-ds.xml
¦   ¦
¦   +---src
¦   ¦   +---conf
¦   ¦   ¦       MANIFEST.MF
¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   +---java
¦   ¦       +---it
¦   ¦           +---myservlets
¦   ¦                   PlaceBidServlet.java
¦   ¦                   PlaceOrderServlet.java
¦   ¦
¦   +---web
¦       ¦   index.jsp
¦       ¦
¦       +---WEB-INF
¦               beans.xml
¦               jboss-web.xml
¦
+---dist
¦       capitolo2.ear
¦
+---nbproject
¦   ¦   ant-deploy.xml
¦   ¦   build-impl.xml
¦   ¦   genfiles.properties
¦   ¦   project.properties
¦   ¦   project.xml
¦   ¦
¦   +---private
¦           private.properties
¦
+---setup
¦       jboss-ds.xml
¦       jboss4-netbeans-destinations-service.xml
¦       log4j.properties
¦
+---src
    +---conf
            chapter2-hornetq-jms.xml
            jboss-app.xml
            log4j.properties
            MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: The log4j.properties file should be at the root of the classpath, when running the application. It doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: I don't understand. Where should I put it in my folder structure? thanks

Comment: I don't know how you build and run your classes. At runtime, it should probably be in the root folder of your jar.

Comment: do you think this error is due only to a bad positioning of log4j.properties file?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. But if it isn't in any classpath, it sure won't work.

Comment: as i wrote below, log4j.properties is in the classpath

Answer (score 40):

Hibernate logging has to be also enabled in hibernate configuration.

Add lines

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

either to

```
server\default\deployers\ejb3.deployer\META-INF\jpa-deployers-jboss-beans.xml
```

or to application's `persistence.xml` in `<persistence-unit><properties>` tag.

Anyway hibernate logging won't include (in useful form) info on actual prepared statements' parameters.

There is an alternative way of using [log4jdbc](http://log4jdbc.brunorozendo.com/) for any kind of sql logging.

The above answer assumes that you run the code that uses hibernate on JBoss, not in IDE.
In this case you should configure logging also on JBoss in server\default\deploy\jboss-logging.xml, not in local IDE classpath.

Note that JBoss 6 doesn't use log4j by default. So adding log4j.properties to ear won't help.
Just try to add to jboss-logging.xml:

```
   <logger category="org.hibernate">
     <level name="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>
```

Then change threshold for root logger. See [SLF4J logger.debug() does not get logged in JBoss 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419394/slf4j-logger-debug-does-not-get-logged-in-jboss-6).

If you manage to debug hibernate queries right from IDE (without deployment), then you should have log4j.properties, log4j, slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12 jars on classpath.
See http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/.

Comment: I have hibernate.show_sql=true in my persistence.xml but it doesn't work. I'll add hibernate.format_sql=true

Comment: I have these jars in my classpath and i run my code from netbeans. I added hibernate.format_sql = true but still it doesn't work :-( I'll read something about jboss-logging.xml

Comment: I doubt you run code in netbeans. IDE just helps you to build ear to deploy on JBoss. Applications code runs actually on appserver that knows nothing about IDE, it's configs or project file structure. JBoss acts depending on just contents of ear and it's own settings. Note that JBoss 6 doesn't use log4j by default. So adding log4j.properties to ear won't help. Keep looking at jboss-logging.xml.

Comment: the code doesn't run in netbeans. I use netbeans for writing my code. Then i deploy the ear on jboss. I hope my explanation is clear. Thanks for your help. I'm reading some docs about jboss.logging.xml but actually i haven't solved my problem

Comment: So you can freely delete log4j.properties and log4j-1.2.15.jar anywhere in your project. In case your own code doesn't use slf4j both  slf4j-api.jar and slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar can also be deleted. Anyway these jars shouldn't be bundled in ear cause they are already present in jboss-6.0.0.Final\common\lib.

Comment: i've updated the answer with hint on changing jboss-logging.xml.

Comment: I saw these tags but i believe they are useful to limit the verbosity of the log. in this case i should see "only" DEBUG messages but i still see nothing :(

Comment: Not "only", all higher levels too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419394/slf4j-logger-debug-does-not-get-logged-in-jboss-6

Answer (score 8):

I answer to myself. As suggested by Vadzim, I must consider the jboss-logging.xml file and insert these lines:

```
<logger category="org.hibernate">
     <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

Instead of DEBUG level I wrote TRACE.
Now don't look only the console but open the server.log file (debug messages aren't sent to the console but you can configure this mode!).

Comment: whats the equivalent file for tomcat?

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot, `v2.3.0.RELEASE`

**Recommended (In application.properties):**

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG //logs all SQL DML statements
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE //logs all JDBC parameters
```

parameters

**Note:**
 
The above will not give you a pretty-print though.
You can add it as a configuration:

```
properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
```

or as per below.

**Works but NOT recommended**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Reason: It's better to let the logging framework manage/optimize the output for you + it doesn't give you the prepared statement parameters.

Cheers

Comment: It makes more sense in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your log4j.properties file should be on the root level of your capitolo2.ear (not in META-INF), that is, here:

```
MyProject
¦   build.xml
¦   
+---build
¦   ¦   capitolo2-ejb.jar
¦   ¦   capitolo2-war.war
¦   ¦   JBoss4.dpf
¦   ¦   log4j.properties
```

Comment: Please verify that any log4j.properties is in your class path. This should not be null (test in Servlet or EJB bean) this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties")

Comment: log4j is in my class path. I wrote `InputStream resourceAsStream  = null;
            resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
            if ( resourceAsStream!=null)
                out.println("log4j is ok");` and the result is "log4j is ok"

Answer (score 0):

We have a tomcat-8.5 + restlet-2.3.4 + hibernate-4.2.0 + log4j-1.2.14 java 8 app running on AlpineLinux in docker.

On adding these 2 lines to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties, I started seeing the HQL queries in the logs:

```
### log just the SQL
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

### log JDBC bind parameters ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=debug
```

However, the JDBC bind parameters are not being logged.

Comment: You should set
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace`
if you want to see bind params in the log.