# Hibernate: analyze "deleted entity passed to persist" on commit()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a complex workflow business call to refactor: this workflow retrieves, updates and delete some entities on the DB.
In the end I try to delete an entity, and once I commit the transaction I get:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist:[com.my.Entity#<null>]
```

I think there's another operation conflicting with this delete, but I cannot figure out which.

It there a way (logging some debug information in Hibernate), on the commit phase, to see the operations associated to each entity?

Is there a way to dump the inner state of the entity manager?

As this operation occurs only once the commit() is fired I cannot sort out where the conflict occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable log and sql trace in your hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

for a fast solution.
If not enought configure your logger like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490617/enable-hibernate-logging).
[Look here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/) for parameters value substitution.