# Hibernate exception: can't prepare statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, derby

I am trying to insert a record into my database which is being handled by Hibernate (Apache Derby). I have a *User* object class which is was mapped using hbm.xml and the database is connecting fine, however returns the following error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 13. Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

**I am getting the following in my log:**

```
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:12 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:12 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.8.Final}
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: titanmusicplayer/dal/mapping/User.hbm.xml
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: titanmusicplayer/dal/mapping/Song.hbm.xml
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: titanmusicplayer/dal/mapping/Playlist.hbm.xml
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:14 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:14 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:14 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:14 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] at URL [jdbc:derby:/test;create=true]
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:14 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:16 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:16 PM org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect <init>
WARN: HHH000430: The DerbyDialect dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects instead
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:16 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator <init>
INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: titanmusicplayer.bll.Playlist (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 42X01
Dec 07, 2013 4:56:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 13.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3057)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3521)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1159)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at titanmusicplayer.dal.dao.UserModel.createUser(UserModel.java:49)
    at titanmusicplayer.TitanMusicPlayer.main(TitanMusicPlayer.java:73)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 13.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:183)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 13.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 13.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

**My user object class:**

```
public class User {

    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private long lastlogin;

    void user(long id, String username, String email, String name, long lastlogin) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastlogin = lastlogin;
    }

    /* GETTERS */

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public long getLastlogin() {
        return this.lastlogin;
    }

    /* SETTERS */ 

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLastlogin(long lastlogin) {
        this.lastlogin = lastlogin;
    }

}
```

**My mapped model for Hibernate (xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 7, 2013 4:55:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="titanmusicplayer.bll.User" table="USER">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="USERNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="EMAIL" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastlogin" type="long">
            <column name="LASTLOGIN" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**My User model:**

```
public class UserModel  {

    public UserModel() {
    }

    public Session startSession() {
        Session s = SessionUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        return s;
    }

    private static void queryUser(Session session) {
        Query query = session.createQuery("from USER");                 
        List <User>list = query.list();
        java.util.Iterator<User> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            User user = iter.next();
            System.out.println("Person: \"" + user.getName() +"\", " + user.getUsername() +"\", " + user.getEmail());
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static void createUser(Session session) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Marcus");
        user.setLastlogin(0);
        user.setEmail("blah@gmail.com");
        user.setUsername(null);
        user.setId(0);
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static List<User> checkLogin(Session s, String email, String password) {
        Query query = s.createQuery("from USER");
        List<User> list = query.list();
        return list;
    }

}
```

**And I call it in Main like this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        UserModel um = new UserModel();
        Session s = um.startSession();
        UserModel.createUser(s);

    }
```

Any help on why I'm getting this exception would be appreciated. Been at this all morning and can't seem to resolve it.

Thanks for suggestions / comments

**EDIT:**

Now receiving this

```
Hibernate: insert into USERS (USERNAME, EMAIL, NAME, LASTLOGIN, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Dec 07, 2013 5:25:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 42Y07
Dec 07, 2013 5:25:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Schema 'ROOT' does not exist
```

Comment: You can enable the SQL logging (show_sql=true) and look what's wrong in generated SQL

Comment: @mmdw thanks, where does the log appear? in the console or is it saved? I can't seem to find it..

Comment: It depends upon the logger configuration. [Enable hibernate logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490617/enable-hibernate-logging)

Comment: Thanks.

receiving this now

`insert into USERS (USERNAME, EMAIL, NAME, LASTLOGIN, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Doesn't seem to be preparing the statement? Or am I wrong?

Comment: The statement syntax is OK now.

Comment: You need to denote the right schema where the tables are. Or you can create the tables in default schema `ROOT` automatically (hbm2ddl.auto=create).

Comment: Where would i do that? Hibernate.cfg.xml ? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User is a reserved word in Derby:  http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html.

If you want your table to be named "user", you will have to enclose the table name in double quotes whenever you reference it.

If you have control over your schema, you might choose a different name for your table. Perhaps "users", or "usertable", or something that is still mnemonic for you, but isn't a reserved word.

Comment: Thank you. Refactored the table to Users... now I'm seeing the following (see above at the end)