# List method doesnt return anything for my list

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I am trying to populate two lists from two different tables, one is called node and the other one fault.

In my model I mapped the classes Node and Fault. And I create the DAO classes.

My first select from node table returns me 1 register, and the second from fault should return 5 register but it doesnt happen.

I thought that it could be happening becauase I am using only one session. I dont know if I have to open other session to do different selects.

Here is my code:

```
public class FaultDAO {
    private Session session;

    public FaultDAO(Session session){
        this.session = session;
    }

    public List<Fault> listaTudo(){
        return this.session.createCriteria(Fault.class).list();
    }
}

public class NodeDAO {
    private Session session;

    public NodeDAO(Session session){
        this.session = session;
    }

    public List<Node> listaTudo(){
        return this.session.createCriteria(Node.class).list();
    }

}
```

I called it here in my JFrame class:

```
 Session session = new HibernateUtil().getSession();
        Excel excel = new Excel();
        excel.criarRelatorio(session);
```

My excel class:

```
NodeDAO nodeDao = new NodeDAO(session);

        List<Node> lista = nodeDao.listaTudo();
```

******Here I populate my workbook, i dont have any problems*

```
FaultDAO faultDao = new FaultDAO(session);

        List<Fault> listaFault = faultDao.listaTudo();
```

* In this point my faultList is empty, it shouldnt be like this

Thanks !

Comment: enable logging first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490617/enable-hibernate-logging

Comment: look my update please

Comment: well, the query for node is there... how Fault is mapped?