# Invalid Column Name Exception in Spring-Hibernate Application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am working on a Spring Hibernate application which uses Oracle 11G database. I have a table from which I want to select three columns and display it in a jsp page. Now, one of the columns has data in the format- abc+def+xyz. I have to display "abc", "def" and "xyz" in 3 different columns in my jsp page. For that, I have written the following query in my DAO:

```
SQLQuery query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT TABLE_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 3) AS FIRST_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 2) AS SECOND_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 1) AS THIRD_COLUMN, USERID FROM TABLE_TABLE1 WHERE USERID='abhi'");
```

The names of my columns are- **TABLE_ID, TABLE_UID, USERID** and the name of my table is- **TABLE_TABLE1**. When I run this, I'm getting-

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name.
```

But the same query when executed in SQL, is giving expected output. I don't understand why I'm getting this discrepancy

Comment: Please describe `TABLE_TABLE1` and paste the result here. Need to check on datatype too

Comment: Also run the statement this sql statements separately in the database and see do you really get any error. `SELECT TABLE_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 3) AS FIRST_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 2) AS SECOND_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 1) AS THIRD_COLUMN, USERID FROM TABLE_TABLE1 WHERE USERID='abhi'`

Comment: @Utsav TABLE_TABLE1 contains a lot of columns. It's actually a pretty huge table. I'll give you the information about relevant columns:
TABLE_ID- Number (19)
TABLE_UID- Varchar2(100 Byte)
USER_ID- VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)

In my POJO class, the variables mapped to these columns are all String, except for the one mapped to TABLE_ID, which is int.

The SQL Statement gives me the desired output when run separately in the DB.

Comment: before that please run the sql statement separately in database and see if it throws the error.

Comment: @Abhineet: If you are using hibernate then column name in select query must be same like you have mentioned it in mapping file. Then and then only hibernate can map your column with your POJO

Comment: @Viraj: Yes. It is the same. But since, I'm splitting one column into three, do I need to have three different entities mapped to it?

Comment: Please turn on [SQL logging in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490617/enable-hibernate-logging) and compare the differences between the executed query and your original query.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting [ or ] characters making the issue(not sure).The other way around you can try using place holders

```
String queryString= "SELECT TABLE_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, ?, 1, 3) AS FIRST_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, ?, 1, 2) AS SECOND_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, ?, 1, 1) AS THIRD_COLUMN, USERID FROM TABLE_TABLE1 WHERE USERID= ?";
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
query.setString(0, "[^+]+");
query.setString(1, "[^+]+");
query.setString(2, "[^+]+");
query.setString(3, "abhi");
```

Comment: No. we're back to "Invalid Column" now

Comment: Are you using any hbm file or mapping entity for this table?

Comment: I'm mapping the entities to my POJO class using Annotations.

Answer (score -1):

It might be because you didn't escape special characters.If so use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` .It has one method:

```
public static String escapeSql(String str);
```

Escapes the characters in a String to be suitable to pass to an SQL query.Please see [java doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String))

In your case it can be:

```
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql("SELECT TABLE_ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 3) AS FIRST_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 2) AS SECOND_COLUMN, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TABLE_UID, '[^+]+', 1, 1) AS THIRD_COLUMN, USERID FROM TABLE_TABLE1 WHERE USERID='abhi'");
SQLQuery query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(escaped );
```

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: It doesn't help. The reason is- All the single quotes in my query are somehow changed to two single quotes after using escapeSql and that in turn is giving the aforementioned exception.

Comment: @Tom I think you missed the point of `escapeSQL`. Please check the example in its Javadoc and compare it with your solution.