# How can I use slf4j 1.7.2 in JBoss 6?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, slf4j, jboss6.x

Logging statements in my code, on the server-side, currently go from the SLF4J 1.7.2 API through the slf4j-log4j12 binding, through JBoss 6's log4j logmanager, into JBoss-logging.

I am eliminating my dependency on log4j.  Client-side, this means switching to logback.  Server-side, I would like to pull out the slf4j-log4j12 binding, but this seems to cause problems.  JBoss 6 bundles its own decrepit slf4j API and binding, but they seem to be from around slf4j 1.5.5.

What is my best option from the following alternatives?

- I can continue to let server-side logging flow through slf4j-log4j12 binding into jboss-logging.  This seems to be best, but I was hoping to throw away the slf4j-log4j12 binding completely as part of getting rid of log4j.  Plus, won't that eliminate a lot of the advantages of using a newer edition of SLF4J?
- Upgrading slf4j API, slf4j-jboss-logmanager, and/or jboss-logging in JBoss 6 so that I can have log statements flow directly from slf4j 1.7.2 API into jboss-logging.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I find new versions of these components?
- Switching to logback on the server-side, which takes me completely outside of JBoss logging and probably means I have to manage a separate logfile.

Comment: So far it looks like continuing with letting the slf4j-log4j12 binding route messages into jboss-logging has the least issues, but that is very unsatisfying...

Answer (score 0):

can you use slf4j-jboss-logmanager to connect slf4j-api to jboss-logging, as in these two questions from Jan ?

[How to 'activate' SLF4J logging in JBoss6 AS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414689/how-to-activate-slf4j-logging-in-jboss6-as)

[SLF4J logger.debug() does not get logged in JBoss 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419394/slf4j-logger-debug-does-not-get-logged-in-jboss-6)